# How to call C#(.NET5 .dll's) from native Android application

Tags: java, c#, android, .net, dll

My organisation has certificated medical `C#`/`.NET5` reasoning engines (e.g. `.dll`'s) that we would like to employ in a native Android application written in Kotlin/Java.

We cannot under amend these certificated `C#` artefacts in any way.

We have investigated `Embeddinator-4000` and `DNNE` and neither these "solutions" work in our case, each having different issues and blockers for us, e.g. `Embeddinator-4000` appears to no longer be supported and over 8 years old.

There is also https://github.com/xamarin/java.interop which appears to be a solution for the reverse case of enabling `java` code to be called from `C#`.

Our requirement is to call (or consume) `C#`/`.NET5` (`.dll`'s) from `Android` `java`/`kotlin` code.

Is this possible without having to refactor the existing `C#` code base in any way?

Comment: The only difference from a class library (dll) and an exe is the exe has a main method.  You could create a console application (acts as a wrapper) that calls the dll.  The exe will run  on Android with out any changes.

Comment: c# is managed so from a c++ (unmanaged) you need to write code like this : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/843f97f0-2dae-4217-8734-91453ab6dd5f/call-managed-c-funciton-from-c?forum=csharpgeneral

Answer (score 1):

You may implement a web api layer to expose the reasoning engines' functions for
the Android application. You need to trade off the performance with the refactor effort.